# getOrgChart 'renderBoxContentEvent' (new 'renderEvent') not working on version 2.0.6

Tags: getorgchart

I'm using getOrgChart for quite a while. With this new update I'm facing some problems. I used the event 'renderBoxContentEvent' (that now was renamed to 'renderEvent'), but now, this new function is never called. Follow the code snippet:

```
orgChart = new getOrgChart(peopleElement, {
        theme: "annabel",
        primaryFields: ["Area", "Nome"],
        photoFields: ["Imagem"],
        linkType: "M",
        enableEdit: true,
        enableDetailsView: false,        
        expandToLevel: 2,
        renderEvent: renderBox,
        renderBoxContentEvent:renderBox,
        updatedEvent: updatedEvent,
        dataSource: dsOriginalCopy,
    });
function renderBox(sender, args) {
    alert(1);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. Could you add some examples of your code, what you try and what you see happening to your question? That will improve the quality of the question and therefore your chance of a good answer.
See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some more tips.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is renamed to renderNodeEvent in version 2.0.7. Here is an example:

```
    var orgchart = new getOrgChart(document.getElementById("people"), {
    renderNodeEvent: renderNodeEvent,
    dataSource: [{id: 1,parentId: null,Name: "Amber McKenzie"}, {id: 2,parentId: 1,Name: "Ava Field"}, {id: 3,parentId: 1,Name: "Evie Johnson"}]
});
function renderNodeEvent(sender, args) {
    args.content[2] = args.content[2].replace("Amber McKenzie", "The name has been replaced");
}
```

See the documentation: http://www.getorgchart.com/Documentation#renderNodeEvent

and download the latest version: 
http://www.getorgchart.com/Download